# Substitute array using cell references in excel

Tags: arrays, excel, replace, substitution

I have a set of cells containing a list of items that I want to run a substitute function on, the data kind of look like this:

```
a,c,d,f,b

a,f,c

b,a,d
```

and I want it so that I replace the a with 1, b with 2, etc...

currently my formula looks like this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"a",1),"b",2),"c",3),"d",4)
```

The formula works great, but there are 2 issues:

1. I have 25 items that require specific substitutions so the nested
   substitution statement gets too long.
2. I'd like to be able to easily manipulate what values get substituted
   in - like changing a value in a vlookup table array - so that I can
   edit it without having to wade through a giant nested substitute
   function. So ideally I'd like something that works like
   `=Substitute(A1,{B1,B2,B3,B4},{C1,C2,C3,C4})` so I can change the values in column B, and C, and have it affect the formula.

Any way to do this with a single formula? My alternative solution is to insert another 25 columns, use a find function on each of the 25 options in its own column, have an if statement that returns a cell reference if my find function exceeds 0, and then concatenate everything together again in a 26th column. I'd rather not use a VBA option since I'm already running a bunch of macros and don't want the added confusion.

P.S. Please note that the `a,b,c,d, 1,2,3,4` data are just representational, the real data are much longer strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the dataset in some excel columns

```
Col S Col T
A      1
B      2
C      3
```

=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,S1,T1),S2,T2),S3,T3),S4,T4)

This will be better to edit and increases readability. 
The alternative for substituting  is creating a macro to loop through the string and replace